# Issue: Working Directory in R Studio "stuck" on directory containing open R Markdown file

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am using the most recent version of R (3.3.2), running in the most recent version of RStudio (1.0.136) on MacOS Sierra (10.12.3). I am running into an issue in which my working directory corresponds, and is stuck on, the directory that contains the .RMD file I currently have open in RStudio. Upon opening the file, the working directory is correctly set to the directory holding the .Rproj file. When I go to load in a file with a path relative to that directory, however, I get an error that there is no such file in the current working directory, and the error returns the location of the .RMD file as that working directory.

The working directory, however (using `getwd()`) still reads where the working directory is *supposed* to be, and no matter where I try to set it, I still get the same error message when I try to read in a file. Notably, I do NOT get an error message that the working directory cannot be changed--R tells me that the working directory has been changed, and that directory is allegedly the current working directory...but it's not.

I have tried fully (as far as I am aware) uninstalling R and R studio and reinstalling them, to no avail. Does anyone have a solution? This is frustrating the heck out of me right now, since I have to revise all the relative paths in the notebooks that I have defined to do my work in the interim.

Extra information in case it's relevant: I restored from a Time Machine backup that I suspect may have been corrupted somehow; some contents of my Applications folder were missing that I had to move over manually. Could this be causing the issue? Are there other system files that R depends on when interacting with the filesystem that I might look to? I'm trying to avoid doing a clean OS install or a piecemeal rebuilding of my files, since I don't know if that's actually the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you change the working directory when *not* using RStudio?

Comment: Are you having problems trying to knit a .Rmd file? If so, all code chunks will treat the root directory as the directory for the .Rmd, not the project. If it's one directory down from your project directory, for example, you can add `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '../')` to make path files relative to the project directory.

Comment: @Gregor Yup! No issue when not using RStudio and writing the same code that is in the .RMD file directly into the R console.

Comment: @SimonJackson The issue is just when I'm trying to run the code inline within the .RMD--I haven't tried knitting anything since the problem arose tbqh.

Comment: Are you knitting a .rmd file or running it as a notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known [feature/bug](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html) of RStudio notebooks (Working Directory about halfway down). Notebooks are executed in the same directory as the file. As @Simon Jackson noted, you can change this using `knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = normalizePath())`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! That seems weird to me, since I'm in a seminar with a number of folks working from the same files, who have different RStudio behavior than I do using the same versions...

I will use that code as a workaround, so thanks!

Comment: Is this by chance new behavior?

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm pretty sure I remember seeing it in the preview release.

Comment: Interesting. I just confirmed with my colleagues that we are using the same version. Instructor distributes .Rmd notebooks that we all run locally, and their code chunks reference whatever working directory they set w/o running any knitr package functions, at least mindfully. I'm perplexed.

Comment: I learned from my instructor that we are not in fact using notebooks, but just plain R markdown files. This is what I thought, but second guessed myself. So, back to square one I suppose.

Comment: If you are using "Run" or "Preview" buttons, and seeing the results in the Source console, you are running a notebook. If you are using "Knit", you are using a markdown. The current version of RStudio assumes you want all .Rmd files to be notebooks.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense--I had missed that part of the documentation. It turns out that most of the other students have disabled the inline notebook behavior in favor of running the .Rmd chunks in the console. Thanks for your help!